# How do I get rid of these weird rectangular irregularities in my glass texture?

Tags: shaders, glass, shader-nodes

[image]

Hi there!
I am trying to show an object inside a glass bottle. I turned screen space reflections and al that stuff on but now I'm getting these weird rectangular irregularities that seem to reflect the inside of the bottle in a weird way. They show up in my renders and in my viewport as seen in the attached image. I tried playing around with the Roughness and IOR values of my glass shader but I keep getting the same results. Anyone who knows what could be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide blend file - might be your geometry/mesh

Answer (score 0):

The blend mode of your material is probably set to alpha blend, try setting it to opaque when using transmission materials in eevee. You can also try to render in Cycles, usually fixes the problem.

Comment: This indeed fixed the problem. Thanks!